# VMware Workstation network setting changes automatically?

Tags: vmware-workstation

This is my Linux guest IP Address setting in VMware Workstation.
Virtual network set to Custom Host-only.

**Linux 1**

```
Network Adapter     :   Custom (VMnet1)     :   192.168.254.11
Network Adapter 2   :   Custom (VMnet2)     :   10.1.1.11
```

**Linux 2**

```
Network Adapter     :   Custom (VMnet1)     :   192.168.254.12
Network Adapter 2   :   Custom (VMnet3)     :   10.1.1.12
```

I noticed a problem when I can't access Linux 2 via SSH from my host PC.

When I changed the static IP config in Linux 2 to DHCP, it turns out 10.1.1.x switched to VMnet1, while 192.168.254.x switched to VMnet3.

**Suddenly on Linux 2**

```
Network Adapter     :   Custom (VMnet1)     :   10.1.1.x
Network Adapter 2   :   Custom (VMnet3)     :   192.168.254.x
```

This is very confusing. I never had this problem with Virtual Box, on the same OS image.

May I know why this happened and how to make the setting persistent?

Comment: Sounds like the order of network adapters could have switched inside the guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

VMnet is the host machine's network interface that guest machine will use.
Each VMnet should be unique for those 2 Linux VMs. e.g.) VMnet1 for Linux1 and VMnet2 for Linux2.

Now you have two options.

1. You still need another VM that will route Linux 1 and Linux 2. meaning you need three total VMs. And configure the router on the 3rd machine. That is the recommended setup.
2. You can also use the Host machine's interface as the router for 2 VMs.

You also need to use the same subnet for each VM and the router.

Use router software or you can also achieve this with iptables.

Comment: VMnet0... VMnetX are virtual *networks*. Virtual network *interfaces* will connect to these *networks*.

Comment: @DanielB Yes it is virtual networks, it doesn't do anything with Host network, but the Host machine manages those. I wrote that way because the OP is getting confused like it is in the guest VM's